# one word or small phrase for the 'first meeting' of 'to be lovers'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

one word or small phrase to perfectly describe the 'first meeting' of 'to be lovers', when they were aloof of each other's existence and all of a sudden their universe collided. Preferably on the poetic side.

Answer (score 0):

**Destined encounter** could satisfy your requirements as *destined* refers to the fate of their universes colliding and *encounter* refers to their first interactions and meeting. The inference with this short phrase is that they were unaware of the other's existence, but I feel like *destined* implies that they did not know of each other prior

> Destined: certain to meet (a particular fate).
>
> Encounter: an unexpected or casual meeting with someone or something

Source: http://www.dictionary.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Diamantaire by Thara Tlau](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=flffCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT98&lpg=PT98&dq=their+first+tryst&source=bl&ots=6S1dpLgM7e&sig=G8fcb18jfIlS9Q8bukb3x815jPo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif6ravvezYAhUiCMAKHXVNADgQ6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=their%20first%20tryst&f=false) describes such an encounter as '**their first tryst**'.

> Tryst : an agreement (as between lovers) to meet

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tryst)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks For the Suggestions folks, but 'destined encounter' doesn't have any poetry in it and "tryst" is something that happens after you are in love.

e.g. : First time when Romeo saw Juliet in the balcony, you cant call it Tryst.. it was pretty much just an 'encounter(destined)' .

I settled on Rendezvous, meeting on a agreed time... or agreed time by destinies in my case.

Comment: This is all just your opinion. Please cite references to support your statements.